# Request timed out: timeout('timed out') in Python's HTTPServer

Tags: python, timeout, basehttprequesthandler

I am trying to create a simple HTTP server that uses the Python HTTPServer which inherits BaseHTTPServer. [https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/http/server.py][1]

There are numerous examples of this approach online and I don't believe I am doing anything unusual.

I am simply importing the class via:
"from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler"
in my code.

My code overrides the do_GET() method to parse the path variable to determine what page to show.

However, if I start this server and connect to it locally (ex: http://127.0.0.1:50000) the first page loads fine. If I navigate to another page (via my first page links) that too works fine, however, on occasion (and this is somewhat sporadic), there is a delay and the server log shows a Request timed out: timeout('timed out') error. I have tracked this down to the handle_one_request method in the BaseHTTPServer class:

```
    def handle_one_request(self):
        """Handle a single HTTP request.
        You normally don't need to override this method; see the class
        __doc__ string for information on how to handle specific HTTP
        commands such as GET and POST.
        """
        try:
            self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
            if len(self.raw_requestline) > 65536:
                self.requestline = ''
                self.request_version = ''
                self.command = ''
                self.send_error(HTTPStatus.REQUEST_URI_TOO_LONG)
                return

            if not self.raw_requestline:
                self.close_connection = True
                return

            if not self.parse_request():
                # An error code has been sent, just exit
                return

            mname = 'do_' + self.command   ## the name of the method is created
            if not hasattr(self, mname):   ## checking that we have that method defined
                self.send_error(
                    HTTPStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED,
                    "Unsupported method (%r)" % self.command)
                return
            method = getattr(self, mname)  ## getting that method
            method()                       ## finally calling it
            self.wfile.flush() #actually send the response if not already done.

        except socket.timeout as e:
            # a read or a write timed out.  Discard this connection
            self.log_error("Request timed out: %r", e)
            self.close_connection = True
            return
```

You can see where the exception is thrown in the "except socket.timeout as e:" clause.

I have tried overriding this method by including it in my code but it is not clear what is causing the error so I run into dead ends. I've tried creating very basic HTML pages to see if there was something in the page itself, but even "blank" pages cause the same sporadic issue.

What's odd is that sometimes a page loads instantly, and almost randomly, it will then timeout. Sometimes the same page, sometimes a different page.

I've played with the http.timeout setting, but it makes no difference. I suspect it's some underlying socket issue, but am unable to diagnose it further.

This is on a Mac running Big Sur 11.3.1, with Python version 3.9.4.

Any ideas on what might be causing this timeout, and in particular any suggestions on a resolution. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, this particular appears to be an issue with Safari. Running the exact same code and using Firefox does not show the same issue.